# DLL load failed when running python manage.py runserver command

Tags: python, django

I'm getting **DLL load failed** when I try to run `python manage.py runserver`. It hapeens when I `cd haddygirl` and then run the previous command.

```
C:\Users\Lazxy\haddygirl>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in 
        wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
        app_config.import_models()
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in 
        import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in 
        <module>
        from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in 
        <module>
        class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 117, in __new__
        new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 321, in 
        add_to_class
        value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)

       File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 204, in 
       contribute_to_class
       self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
       File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
       return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)

       File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
       backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])

       File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
       return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
       File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
       File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 13, 
       in <module>
       from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database

       File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
       from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *

       File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
       from _sqlite3 import *
```

The error:
`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

please help.

Comment: Hi, you should add more details in your question: from my point of view, `python manage.py runserver` is the command you use to run Django. Is it the case?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the driver for connect to sqlite are not found by the python installation.

Please share your python version. After Python 2.7.5 `sqlite3` is shipped as a builtin dependencies.

Have a try with:

1. Use the builtin `sqlite3`
2. Install for python2

```sh
pip install pysqlite
```

3. Install for python3

```sh
pip install pysqlite3
```